# Reading from NSMutableArray throws exception at item 2 even though it exists

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've got a file with a bunch of string in like so:

```
 item1,01-SR,admin,Missing or broken,undefined, 16/04/2013 18:10:10;
 item1,03-SR,admin,In Use,undefined, 16/04/2013 18:10:34;
 item1,01-SR,admin,In Use,undefined, 16/04/2013 18:10:45;
 item1,02-SR,admin,In Use,undefined, 16/04/2013 18:10:49;
 item1,05,admin,In Use,undefined, 16/04/2013 18:10:56;
```

I'm reading the strings in and then splitting them up so I just get one string at a time. Then I want to split up the string I've got again so each CSV is it's own variable. I've tried this like so (numLines is a count of the number of lines in the file):

```
 while (count1 < numLines) {
      NSString *message = [[strings objectAtIndex: count1] copy];

      NSMutableArray *items = [[fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";"]] mutableCopy];

      NSString *items1 = [[items objectAtIndex: count1] copy];

      NSLog(@"items: %@", items1);

      NSMutableArray *inditems = [[items1 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]] mutableCopy];

      NSString * item1 = inditems[0];
      NSString * bnum1 = inditems[1];
      NSString * user1 = inditems[2];
      NSString * state1 = inditems[3];
      NSString * gender1 = inditems[4];
      NSString * tstamp1 = inditems[5];

      NSLog(@"item: %@", item1);
      NSLog(@"bnum: %@", bnum1);
      NSLog(@"user: %@", user1);
      NSLog(@"state: %@", state1);
      NSLog(@"gender: %@", gender1);
      NSLog(@"tstamp: %@", tstamp1);

      count1++;
}
```

Now, this works as far as selecting one line from the file and it puts the first two items into the array and then writes the values of item1 and bnum1 to the log but then it throws an exception for some reason. Now this would usually suggest to me that item 2 doesn't exist in the array so I did a count like so:

```
 NSLog(@"count = %d", [inditems count]);
```

Which correctly returns 6. I then wanted to check that it could actually read another item from the array so I did:

```
 NSString *tstamp1 = [[inditems lastObject] copy];
```

Which when logged correctly returns the time stamps like so:

```
 16/04/2013 18:10:10
```

So I thought "oh at least item 5 works" and tried just getting that item:

```
 while (count1 < numLines) {
      NSString *message = [[strings objectAtIndex: count1] copy];

      NSMutableArray *items = [[fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";"]] mutableCopy];

      NSString *items1 = [[items objectAtIndex: count1] copy];

      NSLog(@"items: %@", items1);

      NSMutableArray *inditems = [[items1 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]] mutableCopy];

      NSString * item1 = inditems[0];
      NSString * bnum1 = inditems[1];
      NSString * tstamp1 = inditems[5];

      NSLog(@"item: %@", item1);
      NSLog(@"bnum: %@", bnum1);
      NSLog(@"tstamp: %@", tstamp1);

      count1++;
}
```

But that also throws an exception! I'm probably doing something stupid here, but I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: NSLog your items, I guess there is blank one.

Comment: As above, the only thing you aren't doing is checking that the array contains n+1 children when you access array[n], which you really should be doing anyway.  Also, if this is production code, I would move the file parsing out of the while loop.

Comment: And BTW how do you get strings? do you use [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]? Then you need to check whether there is blank one or not.

Comment: Right, somehow somewhere I think I had an extra comma which meant that there was indeed a blank field because after I recreated the data file it started working. Thanks for the help anyway guys.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your NSArray *strings is including empty value which is causing your error. You need to check it first and then do your logic.

```
//path is your file path
NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *strings = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
for (int i = 0; i < [strings count]; i++){
   if (![[strings objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]){
   //Here do your code...
   }
}
```